# How to retry xargs commands that have failed up to 5 time

Tags: curl, xargs

I am facing a challenge with my script. I am using xargs with curl to make over 100 000 curl command to an REST API, occasionally some of them will fail with 502 or 504 errors.

What I need to do is retry those curl commands that have failed up to 5 time before giving up.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
cat "$output.txt" | xargs -P 16 -I {} -L 1 curl -u >> response.txt
```

in the output.txt file there are over 100,000 of curl command. 
in response.txt I am capturing the response from curl commands, so I know what has failed. My response.txt file looks like bellow

```
Sending message: 8506 : response: 200
Sending message: 8507 : response: 504
Sending message: 8505 : response: 200
Sending message: 8509 : response: 200
```

how can I change the line of code where xargs is used to retry curl for message 8507 which has failed with 504 error ?

I think it should be possible for me to intercept the 504 errors response before saving in the response.txt file.  However, I do not know how to as xargs to re-try the command that lead to that error.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cat "$output.txt" |
  parallel --retries 5 -P 16 -I {} -L 1 curl -u >> response.txt
```

or:

```
cat "$output.txt" |
  parallel --retries 5 -P 16 curl -u >> response.txt
```